# Plot x lines only using persp()

Tags: r, plot

My code plots both x and y lines but I'd like to plot x lines only. How can I modify my code to do that? Thank you!

```
persp(dem_lower_res,  theta = 0.1, exp = 0.15, phi = 25,
      r = 800,  box = FALSE)
```

dem_lower_res is a rasterlayer

```
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 49, 119, 5831  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.4166667, 0.4166667  (x, y)
extent     : -179.15, -129.5667, 51.08333, 71.5  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 
source     : memory
names      : data_alt 
values     : 1, 2637.287  (min, max)
```

[My code result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBuhg.png)

[What I'd like it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NW2Iq.jpg)

Comment: You need to put together a reproducible example if you want help with this.